# ArcGIS Pro - How to use scale-based sizing at scales larger than 1:1000

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, scale

I'm pretty new to ArcGIS so maybe I'm missing something obvious, but it seems to me that scale-based sizing for symbols is only possible at scales smaller than 1:1000. I can add breaks to the bar at scales between 1:100.000.000 and 1:1000, but for my project (sewer system), I want the symbols in some layers to change size at a scale of 1:50. Is there any way to achieve this? I already tried changing the reference scale of the map, but that doesn't seem to have an any effect.

[image]